# How to disable a form field using ajax in a commandlink of a datatable

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, facelets

I have a form above which captures Contract records and displays them in a datatable which has a commandlink "Edit" tag. When I click “Edit” I would like the form populated with this contract data but with the Contract No field disabled. I’m trying to do this disabling in an Ajax onEvent tag and it is working (ie the disabling). However, the fields are not being populated/displayed in the form when the ajax is being used. If I remove it, everything is fine only that the Contract No will b editable.
These are my edit tags.

```
<h:commandLink id="editLink"  value="#{bundle.ListUnitEditLink}"   >
   <f:ajax   onevent="disablePK" listener="#{contractManager.updateContract}"  />
</h:commandLink>
```

This is my backing bean.

```
public String updateContract() {
    System.out.println("Now in UPDATECONTRACT method and serious debugging");
    current = (Contract) items.getRowData();
    this.newContractId=current.getContractid();
    this.newContractDesc=current.getContractdesc();
    this.newContractDt=current.getContractdt();
    this.newContractAmt=current.getContractamt();
    this.newContractStrtDt=current.getContractstrtdt();
    this.newExpDuration=current.getExpduration();
    this.newCtdBy=current.getCtdby();
    this.newCtdOn=current.getCtdon();
    this.lstUpdBy=current.getLstupdby();
    this.lstUpdOn=current.getLstupdon();
    return "contracts";
}
```

The properties in the bean are being given correct values but they are not appearing in the form to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out my problem by adding render=@all in the ajax tag

```
 <h:commandLink id="editLink"  value="#{bundle.ListUnitEditLink}"  
                                       actionListener="#{contractManager.updateContract}">
         <f:ajax   onevent="disablePK"   render="@all"  />

 </h:commandLink>
```